# How to write helper function for handlebars in Mailgun template

Tags: php, html, templates, handlebars.js, mailgun

I want to modify my handlebars data before my template html document is loaded in Mailgun template.

So to do that I want to write helper functions but I dont know where to write those functions.

This is a similar question to this: [Mailgun - register helpers for templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157909/mailgun-register-helpers-for-templates)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun does not support custom helpers. Your options are:

1. Modify the data before sending it to Mailgun to merge.
2. Take the template out of Mailgun and render the full template before sending.
3. Use a service that supports more advanced templating

Option 1 is probably the easiest implement (depending on what you need to do).

Comment: I see. But a huge problem is that handlebars can store objects as values but we can send objects using their APIs, what is the way around that ? Here is the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585608/how-to-send-array-in-mailgun-handlebars-context